# GPU performance with respect to CPU

Tags: gpu

Why is the GPU more performant in numeric calculations than the CPU? And worse at branching? Can someone give me a detailed explanation of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each SM in GPU is an SIMD processor executing different threads of the warp on each lane of SIMD. Once application is more computation-bound (a few memory accesses) and no branch application achieves the peak FLOPS of GPU. This is due to the fact that upon branch, GPUs mask the one side of divergence and executes the other one first. Both paths are executed serially leaving some SIMD lanes inactive which accordingly drops performance.

I've included a useful Figure from [Fung's paper](http://reference.kfupm.edu.sa/content/d/y/dynamic_warp_formation_and_scheduling_fo_85104.pdf) which is publicly available at the mentioned reference to show how performance actually drops:[image]

Figure (a) shows a typical branch divergence in GPUs occurred inside a warp (4 threads in this sample). Suppose you have following kernel code:

```
A:  // some computation
    if(X){
B:      // some computation
        if(Y){
C:          // some computation
        }
        else{
D:          // some computation
        }
E:      // some computation
    }else{
F:      // some computation
    }
G:  // some computation
```

Threads at A diverge into B and F. As shown in (b) some of the SIMD lanes are disabled over the time dropping performance. Figure (c) to (e) show how hardware serially executes diverging paths and manages divergence. For more information refer to this useful paper which is great starting point.

Compute-bounded applications like matrix multiply or N-Body simulation well mapped to GPUs and return very high performance. This is due to the fact they well occupy SIMD lanes, follow streaming model, and have a few memory accesses.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you are looking for exactly. Assuming it is for general understanding of why do it this way rather than the other way. This article provide a reasonable understanding into your question (in layman terms):

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Why_a_GPU_mines_faster_than_a_CPU

In short:

> A CPU core can execute 4 32-bit instructions per clock (using a
>   128-bit SSE instruction) or 8 via AVX (256-Bit), whereas a GPU like
>   the Radeon HD 5970 can execute 3200 32-bit instructions per clock
>   (using its 3200 ALUs or shaders). This is a difference of 800 (or 400
>   in case of AVX) times more instructions per clock. As of 2011, the
>   fastest CPUs have up to 6, 8, or 12 cores and a somewhat higher
>   frequency clock (2000-3000 MHz vs. 725 MHz for the Radeon HD 5970),
>   but one HD5970 is still more than five times faster than four 12-core
>   CPUs at 2.3GHz (which would also set you back about $4700 rather than
>   $350 for the HD5970).

GPUs are designed for a specific task, namely, to render 3D graphics which require high number calculation. Thus certain applications off-load "number crunching" to GPU, like most modern browsers. Whereas, for branching function, the task is kept with the CPU (for now, who knows what they will do later) as CPU have better "over-lord" function.